# How to create links that thereby change a turtle's breed?

Tags: netlogo

I'm trying to model families. I would like to set it so that males meet females and form a link that will subsequently allow them to reproduce. I have not been able to figure out or find online how to code links to do this although I think it is quite basic.

I have as breeds males and females and husbands and wives. This code is to be run by males.

```
to marry
if hunger < 10 [create-link-with one-of females]
ask my-links [set breed wives]
end
```

This returns a runtime error "you can't see breed to a non-link agentset". I thought this meant that I needed to use some kind of breed-command, e.g.

```
create-<breed>-link-with
```

But

```
create-<wives>-link-with
```

and

```
create-<a wife>-link-with
```

etc all generate error messages.

I have also tried making the link directed, e.g.

```
  create-link-to one-of females
```

but to no avail.

Answer (score 1):

You're having the turtles ask the links rather than the `link-neighbors`, I think that's all:

```
breed [ cats cat ]

to setup
ca
  crt 10 [ setxy random-pxcor random-pycor ]
reset-ticks  
end

to go

  ask one-of turtles [
    create-link-with one-of other turtles 
    ask link-neighbors [
      set breed cats
    ]
  ]
end
```

**Edit**

I think this does what you want:

```
breed [ males male ]
breed [ husbands husband ]
breed [ females female ]
breed [ wives wife ]

males-own [ mood ]

to setup
  ca
  create-males 5 [ 
    set color green
    setxy abs random-pxcor / 2 random-pycor 
    set mood "lonely"
  ]
  create-females 5 [ 
    set color white
    setxy ( abs random-pxcor ) / -2  random-pycor
  ]
  reset-ticks
end

to go
  if any? females [
    ask one-of males [
      set breed husbands
      create-link-with one-of females
      ask link-neighbors [
        set breed wives
      ]
    ]
  ]
end
```

However, you may want to reconsider having the turtles switch breeds, and instead give them all a `turtles-own` boolean variable like `married?` that you can use as a flag. If you want to do the breed switching, do make sure any variables that you create for related breeds are identical- note that in the example above `males` have a `mood` variable but they lose that info when they change breeds to `husbands`.

Comment: That's helpful! Unfortunately, running that generates a different error in the context of the rest of my code: "CREATE-LINK-WITH expected input to be a turtle but got NOBODY instead." If I remove the "ask link-neighbors" line the error disappears. I tried embedding if it in an "if" command, but no joy.

Comment: also (and apologies if this was initially unclear) I only want to change the breed of the link's end. Do I need to make it directed to do that? And if so, do I need something more precise than link-neighbors?

Comment: @Marmitrob 1- Without seeing more of your code I couldn't tell you where that error is coming from- if you edit your question to include your setup and the offending procedure I might be able to sort it. 2- The `link-neighbors` primitive, called by a turtle, will return an agentset comprised of all other turtles linked to that turtle- so if a `male` is linked to two `females` and asks `link-neighbors` to do something, those two females would do that something. I've edited my answer to include another example.